# jQuery or CSS Animate - HTML Element moves down on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set up a timeline, where the marker moves as the user scrolls down. I've set up my code as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="boxone"></div>
<div class="boxtwo"><div class="animatedcircle"></div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.boxone {
  width: 400px;
  height: 4000px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.boxtwo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 4000px;
  background: blue;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.animatedcircle {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 403px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var el = $('.animatedcircle');
    var originalelpos = el.offset().top; // take it where it originally is on the page

    //run on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var el = $('.animatedcircle'); // important! (local)
        var elpos = el.offset().top; // take current situation
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var finaldestination = windowpos + originalelpos;
        el.stop().animate({ 'top': finaldestination }, 400);
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/ElaineM/pen/tIyHB

How would I go about animating the marker to move down when I scroll down?

Answer (score 0):

You mean that circle? If yes, just change .animatedcircle position to fixed.

Comment: In that case, it won't be relative to the scrollbar. It will always be on the fixed position 50px from the top, even if the scrollbar is way down.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uefaG)**

Change position to fixed:

```
.animatedcircle {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 403px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Then in the JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     var el = $('.animatedcircle');
        var originalelpos = el.offset().top; // take it where it originally is on the page
        var incrementer = 0;
        var lastScroll = 0; // used to detect scroll Up event
        //run on scroll
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var el = $('.animatedcircle'); // important! (local)
            var elpos = el.offset().top; // take current situation
          //Sets the current scroll position
          var st = $(this).scrollTop();
          //Determines up-or-down scrolling
          if (st > lastScroll){
             //Replace this with your function call for downward-scrolling
            incrementer += 5;
          }
          else {
             //Replace this with your function call for upward-scrolling
            incrementer -= 5;
          }
          //Updates scroll position
           lastScroll = st;

            var finaldestination = originalelpos + incrementer;
            el.stop().animate({ 'top': finaldestination }, 400);
        });
    });
```

When you use window scroll position, the animatedcircle is going too way down. So instead i have introduced a incrementer which will increase slowly.